# Accessing Dynamically-Named Directory in Python

Tags: python, windows, null

I'm currently putting together a script in Python which will do the following:-

- Create a directory in my Dropbox folder called 'Spartacus'
- Create a subdirectory in this location with the naming convention of the date and time of creation
- Within this directory, create a file called iprecord.txt and information will then be written to this file.

Here is my code thusfar using Python v2.7 on Windows 7:-

```
import os
import time
import platform
import urllib

current_dir = os.getcwd()
targetname = "Spartacus"
target_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, targetname)
timenow = time.strftime("\%d-%b-%Y %H-%M-%S")

def directoryVerification():
    os.chdir(current_dir)
    try:
        os.mkdir('Spartacus')
    except OSError:
        pass
    try:
        os.system('attrib +h Spartacus')
    except OSError:
        pass

def gatherEvidence():
    os.chdir(target_dir)
    try:
        evidential_dir = os.mkdir(target_dir + timenow)
        os.chdir(evidential_dir)
    except OSError:
        pass
    f = iprecord.txt
    with f as open:
        ip_addr = urllib.urlopen('http://www.biranchi.com/ip.php').read()
        f.write("IP Address:\t %s\t %s" % ip_addr, time.strftime("\%d-%b-%Y %H-%M-%S"))


x = directoryVerification()
y = gatherEvidence()
```

I keep on getting an error in line 26 whereby it cannot resolve the full path to the dynamically named directory (date and time) one. I've printed out the value of 'evidential_dir' and it shows as being Null.

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong? Thanks

PS: Any other advice on my code to improve it would be appreciated
PPS: Any advice on how to locate the default directory for 'Dropbox'? Is there a way of scanning a file system for a directory called 'Dropbox' and capturing the path?

Answer (score 1):

`os.mkdir()` does not return a pathname as you might be thinking. It seems like you do inconsistent methods of the same thing at different spots of your code.
Try this:

```
evidential_dir = os.path.join(target_dir, timenow)
os.mkdir(evidential_dir)
```

And fix your other line:

```
f = "iprecord.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.mkdir` doesn't return anything.

```
evidential_dir = target_dir + timenow
try:
    os.mkdir(evidential_dir)
except OSError:
    pass
os.chdir(evidential_dir)
```